# Check if download of CSV was aborted in R

Tags: r, url, download, abort

I hope some of you folks can help me.

**What I'm doing**

I'm downloading a csv file daily from an azure cloud with

```
out <- tryCatch(
          
          {
            download.file(myurl,filepath)
          },
          
          error=function(cond) {
            message(paste("URL does not exist."))
            message(paste("Here's the original error message: ",message(cond)))
            
          },
          
          warning=function(cond) {
            message(paste("URL caused a warning."))
            message(paste("Here's the original warning message: ",message(cond)))
          },
          
          finally={
            
          }
        )
```

**Problem**

However, sometimes the download aborts and only parts of the csv are downloaded.
There is no error or warning then, the code just continues without me noticing that the file is corrupted.

**Question**

How can I detect if the download aborts?

**Fixes I've checked so far**

I checked if I can compare the file sizes (before download and how much was actually downloaded) to test if everything worked fine. The function `download.file` prints the file size before and after downloading:

```
trying URL '...'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 533296848 bytes (508.6 MB) ## size before starting download
downloaded 508.6 MB   ## how much was actually downloaded
```

But I haven't figured out yet, how I can retrieve that information from the function to use it.

I also tried to compare the final file size on disc and the file size on azure before downloading.

```
file.info(filepath)$size # file size on disc
[1] 533861520

# versus

header <- httr::HEAD(myurl)
header$headers$`content-length` # file size in cloud
[1] 533296848

#### some output of header$headers (As asked for in the comments)
$`x-ms-lease-status`
[1] "unlocked"

$`x-ms-lease-state`
[1] "available"

$`x-ms-blob-type`
[1] "BlockBlob"

$`x-ms-server-encrypted`
[1] "true"

$`x-ms-access-tier`
[1] "Hot"

$`x-ms-access-tier-inferred`
[1] "true"
```

However, the size of the file on azure and the final file size on disc differ from each other, even if the download was succesful. So I can't use these information.

**Further details**

OS Windows 10 64,
R 3.6.1

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the differences are small, it could be due to encoding differences. Could you print the `header$header`?

Comment: `file.info` can be used to get the file size after it is downloaded but the units may be different so you may have to convert them.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, thank you for your input.

`file.info(filepath)$size` gives 533,861,520. `header$headers$content-length` gives 533,296,848. Interestingly `download.file` gave 508.6 MB and in File Explorer the csv is listed with 521,350 KB. Does any conversion fit here?

Comment: @Sirius, which information do you need from `header$headers`?
`content-length` = 533,296,848; `accept-ranges` = bytes.

Comment: I was looking for anything encoding related. If one side is considering raw bytes, whereas the other side is consdiering encoded characters, the reported size may differ

Comment: @Sirius, thank you. I posted some seemlingly more relevant outputs of `header$headers` in the questions itself. The formatting here in the comments make them hard to read

Comment: Do you have a similar csv file you could share publicly for us to debug better, also try reading the csv file into R as simple text and check length nchar. Try reading it asr raw as well and check. Does the file contain characters that suggest encoding errors might be the root of this problem?

Comment: @Sirius, I can try to create such a file. It contains German Umlauts like ä, ö, ü.
Is there really no other way to check if a download aborted than comparing file sizes on disc and in cloud? Maybe other downloading functions provide a suitable feature and I just don't know them?

Comment: That is the explanation, I can guarantee. If you put the letters ä, ö and ü in a text file and save it, you will see that if it is _latin-1_ encoded it will take up 4 bytes. If it is encoded with _UTF-8_ it will be 7 bytes. Try this yourelf, if you are able. When you compare sizes I bet they are encoded differently at both ends. You need to fix or understand how this affects your data file before you can use these sizes to make a decision.

Comment: Thanks @Sirius for the explanation. I checked and indeed, for every Umlaut my examplary UTF-8 file grows. So I can not use the file size for checking if the download was complete, as the file has half a million entries and growing and I can not predict how many Umlauts there will be in the file beforehand. So either I use the output of `file.download` which seems to be consistent, or I find another way to check if the download was complete.